# Reason to use a stage instance rather than calling 'stage'?

Tags: actionscript-3

Afraid that I may be over-thinking this and also do not know which keywords I should be using to find more information. Needless to say my searches are proving futile. I would like to know if there is a reason that, within an AS3 class, I would want to do something like this:

```
var myStageInstance:Stage;

//within an arbitrary class
var myStageInstance:Stage = stage;
myStageInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent, someFunction);
```

as opposed to something that I would normally do:

```
//within an arbitrary class
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent, someFunction);
```

There is no particular problem that I am looking to solve right now. **I would just like to know if there is a reason to use one method over the other.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the follow code will not work it is broken as myStageInstance is null until you assign it something.

```
var myStageInstance:Stage;
//within an arbitrary class
myStageInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent, someFunction);

//You need to do 
var myStageInstance:Stage = stage;
myStageInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent, someFunction);

//this is more preferred as it is a lot less code. 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent, someFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry, overlooked the stage assignment - I will update the question. I only specified the type. Still, would be great to know the functional difference between the two methods. Logically I understand that using 'stage' is simply easier and cleaner out-of-the-box.

Comment: The only real difference between the 2 is one is a global var(stage) and the other is a locally scoped var(myStageInstance), but because objects are passed by reference there is really no difference between the 2.

Comment: At best the only thing I can think of is if you want to extend the stage class. However, I am not even sure if this is possible it might be a final class and probably is.

Comment: Is it possible to pass 'stage' to a function as a variable rather than 'myStateInstance'? That is one case I am not sure of. Thinking it over and that is the only possible exception that I have come up with so far.

Comment: stage is an object in general so yes you can However it will be null until the code that is being run has been added to stage with the event "addedToStage"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are reasons to maintain a reference to the stage.  One example is if you are adding event listeners to the stage and need to be sure they are cleaned up in the future or want direct control over when the events come in.  Here's an example:

```
public class Demo
{
    private var _stage:Stage;

    public function Demo()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage, false, 0, true);
    }

    public function destroy():void
    {
        if (_stage)
        {
            _stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
            _stage.removeEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onMouseLeave);
            _stage = null;
        }
    }

    private function onAddedToStage(event:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        _stage = stage;

        _stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove, false, 0, true);
        _stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, onMouseLeave, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
    { /* Do something */ }

    private function onMouseLeave(event:Event):void
    { /* Do something */ }
}
```

Comment: So in your case instead of having to track the stage listeners you now need to track the Demo instance. Still seems pointless.

Comment: I think checking _stage for null is more performant than checking willTrigger/hasEventListner.  Plus, those functions will find listeners added by other Classes, and that may not be what you want.

Comment: Like I said, I do it when I want to maintain my own references.  I've found it quite useful, and far more easier to debug than relying on the display list for managing my references.  It's a pain to dive into the display list when working inside a breakpoint in the Flash Builder IDE.  With a hard variable reference, the value is right there.  I know it seems a little more "hands-on" than necessary, but I've found it incredibly helpful over the course of many projects.
There is probably a speed benefit, but it's not my reason for choosing to keep my own references in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should not work, since you are not setting your stageInstance to anything.

I can't see a reason why you would ever use anything other than `stage` to refer to the stage instance provided, since it is practically a non-global singleton.